# Organizing templates in sub-directories in Play

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Can I organize my view templates in subdirectories in play 2.1?

I get an compiler error if I have a structure something like this: `app/views/common/component.scala.html`

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ok, the import in the controller needs to be `import views.html.common.*`

Answer (score 16):

Yes , You can structure your template in sub directory.
What error you are getting ?? .You may be getting error due to some other reason.
if you use app/views/common/component.scala.html
then u can access your template from scala class as **views.html.common.component()**

From html : **@common.component**

Comment: I solved the problem. I expected the import statement with `views.common..` and not `views.html.common..`